Flask + Auth0 v2 : After hours of stress, still getting "Failed to exchange token" error
I'm making a Flask Web App and am trying to use Auth0 v2 by Okta for the authentication process. Because it is still in development stages, I'm hosting it locally on http://127.0.0.1:5000, and since Auth0 needs the login/callback/logout/etc. links to be on https, I'm hosting using ngrok (at https://5792-2600-1015-b0cf-8c0-1d00-51a3-1925-8664.ngrok-free.app).
I'm getting this error after pressing the 'Sign in' button:
{ "error": "Failed to exchange token" }
From my Auth0 logs, it shows that the login was successful, so I'm thinking it's a problem with the callback/receiving functions.
Here is all my Auth0 code (python):
@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    state = request.args.get('state')
    code = request.args.get('code')

    print(f"Callback URL: {request.url}")
    print(f"State in session: {session.get('oauth_state')}")
    print(f"State in request: {state}")
    print(f"Code received: {code}")

    # Verify that the state matches
    if state != session.get('oauth_state'):
        print("State does not match! CSRF Warning!")
        return jsonify({"error": "Invalid state parameter"}), 403

    # Exchange the authorization code for an access token
    try:
        token = oauth.auth0.authorize_access_token()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during token exchange: {str(e)}")
        return jsonify({"error": "Failed to exchange token"}), 500

    # Get user information
    user_info = get_user_info(token['access_token'])
    
    if user_info:
        session['user'] = user_info  # Store user info in session
        session.pop('oauth_state', None)  # Clear state
        return redirect('/dashboard')  # Redirect to the dashboard
    else:
        return jsonify({"error": "Failed to fetch user info"}), 500

def get_user_info(access_token):
    url = f'https://{AUTH0_DOMAIN}/userinfo'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()  # Return user info as a dictionary
    return None

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    user_info = session.get('user')  # Retrieve user info from the session
    if user_info:
        return render_template('dashboard.html', user=user_info)  # Render the dashboard with user info
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))  # Redirect if not authenticated

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(f'https://{AUTH0_DOMAIN}/v2/logout?returnTo={url_for("index", _external=True)}&client_id={CLIENT_ID}')

(of course, I have a auth0.env file and I get the data from it properly)
After multiple prompts, even ChatGPT can't help!
I would really appreciate some help, because this has been taking a while.
I usually develop in the front end, and from my research I concluded that I'm probably the only one who gets this error lol.

What's the actual exception? That is, what is e in the trace callback from this line print(f"Error during token exchange: {str(e)}")?

Here is the error: Error during token exchange: mismatching_state: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response. although the printed state in session and state in request (i printed them to the output) are the same: State in session: DGJ3vmc9CjOfhTyoh_uU8g State in request: DGJ3vmc9CjOfhTyoh_uU8g
